# Progress bar value update auto in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

i want to copy one file from folder to another and progress bar value updates from 0% to 100% while copying the file
how can i do that?
i tried to make that but the progress bar value only update to 100% after the copying finished.
can anyone help me? 
code with vb.net in Visual Studio 2012

Comment: Well...we'd need to know how you are actually copying the file...

Comment: the code for copying is :     My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(path & ".....", path & "....1", True)

Comment: You have to copy the file on the background thread and the progress bar update on UI thread. But you have to show what you have done so far.

Comment: what's the code please?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [CopyFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.myservices.filesystemproxy.copyfile?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_VisualBasic_MyServices_FileSystemProxy_CopyFile_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_VisualBasic_FileIO_UIOption_) override that allows you to pass in a [UIOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.uioption?view=netframework-4.8) of `AllDialogs` which will show progress:

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(path & ".....", path & "....1", FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs)
```

If you need the overwrite option then you'll have to manually DELETE the existing file beforehand.

If you want finer control, then you'll have to abandon the one-liner using `CopyFile()` and write your own function that copies the file using streams and bytes so you can display progress however you want.  This would be significantly different than what you are doing now.